# Multiple objects in PFQueryTableViewController - Parse.com

Tags: iphone, ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to display two objects or "classNames" into a `PFQueryTableViewController`. Here is my code so far with only one object. I can't seem to be able to add more than one object.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Customize the table

        // The className to query on
        self.className = @"Funny";
        //self.className = @"Story";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"title";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 100;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add more `@property`s to your view controller. Make sure to add the necessary ones (className2, textKey2, etc) and to modify the datasource methods of your table view to display the data.

That being said, it seems strange the the view controller is initiated with `initWithCoder`. That is usually the method invoked by storyboard for views.

Comment: Where would I do that? In the frame work (PFQueryTableViewController.h)? Do you have a better way instead the initWithCoder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used two object when saving the post. It worked perfectly!

```
 PFObject *quoteNew = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"New"];
[quoteNew setObject:[[self attribution] text] forKey:@"by"];
[quoteNew setObject:[[self quoteText] text] forKey:@"quoteText"];
[quoteNew setObject:[[self attributionTitle] text] forKey:@"title"];



[quoteNew saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self done:self];

    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh. Somthing went wrong"
                                    message:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    }

}];


PFObject *quote = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Funny"];
[quote setObject:[[self attribution] text] forKey:@"by"];
[quote setObject:[[self quoteText] text] forKey:@"quoteText"];
[quote setObject:[[self attributionTitle] text] forKey:@"title"];


[quote saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        [self done:self];

} else {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh. Somthing went wrong"
                                message:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"]
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                      otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}

}];
```

}